# Changing the range of cells multiple times in a single formula

Tags: excel

I have quite a large workbook with countless formulas in it. Some of the formulas have been using different columns with a count range from 3 - 1900( shown below) However, I need to change the range to 5000. Is there any way to do this without changing each one manually?

```
=COUNTIFS('West Data'!$F$3:$F$1901,"Male",'West Data'!$K$3:$K$1901,"Adult Acute",'West Data'!$T$3:$T$1901,"3",'West Data'!$M$3:$M$1901,'All W Data Set'!$F$4)
+COUNTIFS('West Data'!$F$3:$F$1901,"Male",'West Data'!$K$3:$K$1901,"Adult Acute",'West Data'!$T$3:$T$1901,"3+",'West Data'!$M$3:$M$1901,'All W Data Set'!$F$4)
+COUNTIFS('West Data'!$F$3:$F$1901,"Male",'West Data'!$K$3:$K$1901,"Adult Acute",'West Data'!$T$3:$T$1901,"3++",'West Data'!$M$3:$M$1901,'All W Data Set'!$F$4)
```

Many thanks,

Tristan

Comment: Use find/replace.  FWIW your formula can be simplified to: `=SUM(COUNTIFS('West Data'!$F$3:$F$1901,"Male",'West Data'!$K$3:$K$1901,"Adult Acute",'West Data'!$T$3:$T$1901,{"3","3+","3++"},'West Data'!$M$3:$M$1901,'All W Data Set'!$F$4))`

Comment: Thanks Scott - works a treat. The simplified formula is great as I tried everything except adding the SUM at the beginning. Seems obvious now - doh!!

Answer (score 0):

*From question comments*:

> `=SUM(COUNTIFS('West Data'!$F$3:$F$1901,"Male",'West Data'!$K$3:$K$1901,"Adult Acute",'West Data'!$T$3:$T$1901,{"3","3+","3++"},'West Data'!$M$3:$M$1901,'All W Data Set'!$F$4))`
>
> -Scott Craner